# Jest - is it possible to test specific variables within an async module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, jestjs

I am wondering if it is possible to test variables for specific values within a module call. For example:

```
module.exports = async(request, context, postgres) => {

   let userId = request.user.id;
   let balanceQuery = 'SELECT balance FROM account WHERE user_id = $1';
   let userBalanceStr = await postgres.query(balanceQuery,[userId]).then(result => result.rows[0].balance);
   let totalCount = BigFunction(userBalanceStr);
   ......
}
```

How would I go about testing/accessing the value of `balanceQuery` or `userBalanceStr` within a jest test?

I'm only able to access the `userId` portion of the query, and I am sort of confused how to go about accessing other variables within the module.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by mocking `postgres.query` and `BigFunction` and then asserting the arguments passed in each call. And to be able to test the async code, you can implement an async [test](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await).
API reference: [Mock Functions](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html)
When mocking `postgres.query`, you could implement a fake returning value, which will be assigned to `userBalanceStr`, and then can be asserted with the mocked `BigFunction`.
To mock `BigFunction`, you can either mock its [importation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/es6-class-mocks.html#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock) present in the module under test, or changing the exported function to pass `BigFunction` as a dependency, like `postgres`, passing the mock function directly as argument.